# converting projects to single dll

Tags: .net, dll

i have finished my web site ,i used netiers to generate DAL and then i copied the .data and .datasqlclinet and .entities projects to my website and add a reference to them and i use the netiers functions and proc to develop my site ,,but i wana know how to add this 3 projects generated by netiers to a single dll and use it in my site instead of adding the 3 projects ,so can anyone tell me how i do this ...
thnx in advance

Comment: Can we assume you're talking about .NET?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can do this using webdeployment project. There is an option to specify compile to a single dll (can't remember exactly).

Comment: i used it, and i made a strong name for the solution but when i build the web deployment project ,it gives me the .data project doesnt have a strong name and .entities project doesnt have a strong name ,,can u tell me what to do

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to merge DLLs? [ILMerge](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/people/mbarnett/ilmerge.aspx) can do the trick.